# Setting Proxy Windows IOT Core

Tags: c#, proxy, .net-core, windows-10-iot-core

I am working on a project with a raspberry 2 with windows iot core.
Where i need to send data to a Swagger api, but the corporate proxy on my location blocks the messages. I can't find any clear solution on how to bypass or use the proxy for iot core.
Here is my base code for sending data to the api, it works outside the proxy but not in it.

```
public async void sender(string link, object value)
{

    string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);

    var client = new HttpClient();

    try
    {
        var response = (await client.PostAsync(link, new StringContent(jsonData, 
                                           Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using PowerShell to manually set the gateway IP address for the network connection to something other than that of the proxy server (which I assume DHCP is providing)?

Something like this:

```
$adapter = Get-NetAdapter `
    -Name Ethernet

New-NetIPAddress `
    -InterfaceAlias $adapter.Name `
    -AddressFamily IPv4 `
    -IPAddress 192.168.1.55 `
    -PrefixLength 24 `
    -DefaultGateway 192.168.1.1; 

Set-DnsClientServerAddress `
    -InterfaceAlias $adapter.Name `
    -ServerAddresses ("192.168.1.2","192.168.1.3")
```

Use the IoT Dashboard app to create a PowerShell session to your device. It just handles setting up the remote service commands for you.

If you not familiar with doing that check out the IoT Dashboard section here:

http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2016/06/controlling-your-windows-10-iot-core-device/

Comment: I tried, but it did not work, it even blocked me from using powershell to connect to the pi.

Comment: @user6546520 That's annoying. If you had a Pi3 you could create 2x network connections... Wired to the local network with proxy. Then WiFi to something unrestricted and temporary for admin/dev. Eg. Tethered to your phone.